# Office 365 SharePoint friendly URL

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I am migrating to Office 365 sharepoint from on-prem sharepoint 2016. Currently, users have to just type in http://intranet and will be taken to sharepoint. Is there a way to do something like this in Office 365 sharepoint? I just want the migration to be easier on users. We also have an internal DNS server.

Answer (score 3):

You can set up a web server (IIS, Apache, nginx, etc.) to perform an HTTP 301 redirection. You cannot use a custom domain name in SharePoint Online.

Comment: So i wouldn't be able to use a CNAME record, correct? I ultimately want users to type http://intranet and then be directed to https://companyname.sharepoint.com/sites/intranet

Comment: No, DNS cannot route you to a specific URL regardless. You'd need to use a 301 redirect.

Answer (score 2):

There is a DNS type solution to the problem by using http://redirect.center/ (more details including open source code can be found at this site)

NAME: share
TYPE: CNAME Record
TARGET: company.sharepoint.com.redirect.center
 for share.company.com to redirect to company.sharepoint.com.

For share.company.com/path to go to comany.sharepoint.com/path use
NAME: share
TYPE: CNAME Record
TARGET: company.sharepoint.com.redirect.center

However the url in the browser will be company.sharepoint.com/path , but you can type share.company.com/path in the box.

I hope this helps anyone still hoping for a solution.

I myself have been looking for a solution for some time and found this working solution really helpful.